# How to read raw variables from a file in PHP?

Tags: php, html, file

This may be simple to do, sorry if this is quite broad. I am fine with looking for any alternatives, but I would just like some help.

I need to be able to read variables from a file in PHP.
For instance, I would have a file like this:

```
$test = 10
$greeting = "Hello"
```

And PHP would be able to take these values and actually use them. The "code" above would be the entire file, add or take a few variables. The reason why I need to do it like this is so that other PHP files can also write variables to it. Is there any method that can do this, or something similar to this.

Thanks

Edit: This file would be a TXT file; it's not meant to be .php

Comment: this file is `.php` file or `.txt` file?

Comment: @AlivetoDie .txt file, thanks

Comment: Is your file meant to be PHP code or structured data?  If it's PHP code, you're missing the semi-colons.  And you can just `include()` it like any other PHP code file.  If it's meant to be structured data, why re-invent the wheel?  Use JSON or XML or some other standard data format for which tools exist to read/write the file.

Comment: You can write a short parser to read in each line, split it on `=`, and grab the variable name and value.

Comment: [PHP: Filesystem Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). As an aside, just use a regular PHP script or a database to do this.

Comment: @David It wasn't meant to be a PHP file, just a file that stores variables.

Comment: @Jamie  since it's a `.txt` file. So what you are thinking ( just a file that stores variables.) is not happening actually. `.txt` file save every thing as sting not variable

Comment: @Jamie: If it's not code then don't treat it like code.  Functionality already exists for reading and writing JSON data: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php  Understand also that the responsibility becomes yours to ensure that none of your processes are reading/writing the file at the same time.  Databases protect against that automatically, but files do not.  Beware of race conditions.

Comment: Use a database to save and share information among processes, not random, unstructured files. Down this road lies only madness.

Answer (score 0):

Read lines from your text file:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("variables.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
// Output one line until end-of-file
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  //echo fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
  // <Your code logic here.>
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

For each iteration of the while loop do whatever it is you need to do with the values read in from the text file.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't answer the main question.  I would just use include.  It doesn't matter which extension an include file has, I often call them .inc or so.  (I do agree on your answer what holds the turtle up)

Answer (score 0):

I found a method. I'm still fairly new to PHP, so I'm using it quite strictly. I've decided to make a never ending PHP file, with all my variables in it:

```
<?php
//File name is variables.php
$test = 10;
$greeting = "Hello";
```

So then other PHP files can still write to it and other PHP files can read from it:

```
<?php
include "variables.php";
echo $greeting;
```

Output would be Hello.
  Thank you for all your help everyone.